# How can I get Blender to correctly render the hair color?

Tags: texturing, transparency

I have a model extracted from an online source using AssetStudio.  Everything seem to be working correctly; the model, the armature, the animations, and the textures--except for the hair portion of the textures.  The models' hair comes through as fluorescent.  Here's the original textures, in .PNG format with RGB and alpha channels intact:

[image]

In that picture, the hair portion is the multicolored blob at the lower right, and the yellowish bits in the upper right are for wisps of hair.  When I re-save the image as a .JPG (in order to get the skin and everything else to look right:

[image]

Now the alpha channel is stripped away and the skin portion looks correct, but nothing changed with the hair portions.  I do know that when I extract the alpha channel, it works as a transparency as expected, but the base colors of the hair are all wrong.  Here's what it looks like when applied to the model:

[image]

Obviously not the way it's intended to look.  This happens with every character I've extracted from this source that has hair. I'm sure it's some quirk of the program itself that is handled programmatically in the game's galleries to make the hair display correctly.  I'm hoping somebody can understand it and give me a way to use Blender to compensate for it.  How do I do this?

Comment: I expect the character has a black (or dark braun) color hairs ... colorful thing could be a Normal map. So probably we need to see your node setup or check your simplified blend (hair part?). Even your screens of texture in JPEG is not original PNG so we are only guessing ... some game textures are using RGB channels to store non-color informations (glossy, metal, or what ever). Or it can be just a node tree. I'm not sure if we can help from given info ... probably someone specifically with AssetStudio knowledge ... or it isn't probably related to Blender at all, but 2D texture extractor.

Comment: You're right, the character should have dark hair.  The character also comes with a separate normals map, so I don't believe that's the case here.  My node setup for the hair is a simple Principled BSDF with the .PNG version plugged in as the Base Color, and the alpha channel of that same image texture plugged into the alpha on the BSDF, and with the transparency set to Alpha-Hashed.

I know this is a quirk of the game, but my hope was that Blender could insert some sort of translator between the texture and the BSDF nodes to convert the colors into the correct ones.

Comment: Like I wrote, you should share your blend to speed this conversation up ... Just the head with original textures packed. Thanks